# How to test function within Angular click-handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm currently unit-testing my Angular controllers and the only portion of my code coverage that is lagging behind are functions within click-handlers, and the statements within these functions.

As an example, `function(cap)...` states `function not covered` and `playersService.setCap...` states `statement not covered` in relation to the below click-handler:

```
vm.setCap = function(cap) {
  playersService.setCap({playerId: playerId}, {limit: cap});
};
```

How would I go about testing a function like this, and the statement within it? I'm just looking for a basic test (`expect(function).toHaveBeenCalled`).

Comment: so is vm.setCap your event handler?, Are you trying to test that playersService.setCap gets called, just trying to tailor my answer.

Comment: Exactly. I call `vm.setCap` within my test, but after that I'm not sure how to test that the function within it was called.

Comment: I assume playersService is an injected service?

Comment: Right, it's an injected service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright to test this you would want to use a mock version of your playersService which you can then just inject into your controller.

```
describe("Controller: yourController", function () {
var mockResponse = {};
var mockService = {
    setCap: function(playerId, limit){
        mockResponse.playerId = playerId,
        mockResponse.limit = limit
    }
};

var mockParams = 'cap';
var $controller;
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
}))
it("Should call the service on click", function () {
    spyOn(mockService, 'setCap').and.callThrough();
    var testedController = $controller('yourController', { playersService:mockService });
    testedController.setCap(mockParams);
    expect(mockService.toHaveBeenCalled).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockResponse.limit.limit).toBe(mockParams);
})
});
```

This will give you an example for both white and blackbox testing for the functionality.